# Multiple Images in Container with Zoom In-Out button, Next Previous button, Image Count Same like Google Pdf Viewer

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am looking for a Image Container with Zoom-In and Out Button, Next-Previous Button, Active Image with Total Count Same like Google Pdf Viewer...

Is There any Container like that in Jquery ?? Comments are welcomed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Guyz.. I have found a Jquery Library "iViewer" Here is the link : [Click Here](http://test.dpetroff.ru/jquery.iviewer/test/) which worked .. well according to my scenario.